# Meaning of "commutes with all the elements in G"

Tags: linear-algebra

In section 3.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.08599,

> Characterizing linear $G$-equivariant layers can be reduced to the task of solving a set of linear equations in the following way: We are looking for a linear operator $L:\mathbb{R}^\ell\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^\ell$ that commutes with all the elements in $G$, namely:
> \begin{equation}
> L(g\cdot x)=g\cdot L(x),\ x\in\mathbb{R}^\ell,\ g\in G.\tag{3}
> \end{equation}

In the above, what does it mean that "commutes with all the elements in $G$"?

Comment: It is explicitly defined in the next line after the highlighted part.

Comment: It means that $L(g \cdot x) = g \cdot L(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^\ell$ and $g \in G$.

Comment: “Namely” indicates that they are getting ready to precisely define what they mean.